# python chain class for piecewise_func

Tags: python, chain

i want to make a class piecewise_func that will work like

```
F = piecewise_func(0,100)(10,122)
```

I can add values like

```
F = F(30, 0)
```

And get get y value like:

```
 F.y(5)
```

'y = 111'
Any thoughts how i can realize that?)
I tried to make

```
    class piecewise_func:
    def __init__(self, x:list, y:list):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def y(self, x):
        pass

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return piecewise_func(self._x + x, self._y + y)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._y)
```

I know that it just sum x and y but i don't know how to extend my list of x and y
Thank you!

Comment: mmm... could you add an expected output? in the constructor you have `list` annotations but in your examples you use integers numbers. Do you want extend the list or sum?

Comment: i just want to add values when i call F(30, 0). And get value when i call F.y(5)

Comment: What does `F(30, 0)` represent? A piecewise function is usually defined as a function that has different definitions for different subsets of its domain. I don't know what `piecewise_func(0, 100)(10, 122)` is supposed to mean. I would imagine something like `F = piecewise_func([((x0,x1), f), ((x1, x2), g)])`, then `F(x)` would determine which interval `x` falls in to decide whether to return `f(x)` or `g(x)`.

Comment: As a concrete example, you can think of `abs` as a piecewise linear function where it's `lambda x: -x` for negative `x` and `lambda x: x` otherwise.

Comment: It means that you just add a point
Like x = 30, y = 0

Comment: @chepner I think the OP want a way to append data to a list using "piecewise calls", no reference to mathematics

Comment: Something like `piecewise_func.add(30, 0).add(10, 122)` would be a lot clearer than chaining calls together. Save `__call__` for what `y` does.

Comment: `piecewise_func.add(30,0).add(10,122)(10) == 122`

Answer (score 0):

Reedit due comments:

```
class piecewise_func:
    def __init__(self, x:int, y:int):
        self._x = [x]
        self._y = [y]

    def y(self, x):
        pass

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        self._x += [x] # update the lists
        self._y += [y]
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f'x: {self._x}\ny: {self._y}'


F = piecewise_func(0, 100)
G = F(10, 122)
H = G(1, 2)

print(F)
#x: [0, 10, 1]
#y: [100, 122, 2]
```

Notice that `F`, `G`, `H`, ... will point to the same object so you can also use `print(G)` or `print(H)`

Comment: yes, but you have to modify the constructor. I will edit it

Comment: Ok, so any thoughts how i can get the value using F.y(5)

Comment: @MONEY LONGER what does `5` represent in `F.y(5)`?

Comment: it's x of our function

Comment: @MONEY LONGER yes, that's what the signature of the method also says. Could you please add some more details? What is `5` and what does the `y`-method do?